# Batch file getting "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have been working on helping to resolve a batch file error per the title. It is attempting to run an .exe and output a file to a UNC, but keeps failing to find path specified.

```
"C:\program files\gnupg\gpg.exe" --recipient "TU_MFT_PRD_2025" --output "\\servername\folder\data\folder\crfolder\TU\logs\ps.edtin.bmtg.php" --encrypt "\\serverfolder\data\folder\cb\TU\trnu.fil" pause
```

I did not write this, and do not have much experience to find a solution. Is there anything that could be missing in the code to address the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GnuPG](https://gnupg.org/download/) is either missing, or
installed in a different folder.

Search for a file named `gpg.exe` on the disk. If you find it,
then you need to correct the path in the batch file.

If `gpg.exe` is not found, then it needs to be downloaded and
installed, and the path in the batch file needs to be verified
or corrected.